# Decode Base64 on HTML

Tags: html, base64

I have my HTML code on Base64, and I want it to be decoded and run when website opens, how can I do it?

I can't post the code here, it's too big.
I tried `window.atob` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript. There are two functions for doing this, `btoa` and `atob`.

**Example:**

```html
<script>

var message = "Hello world"

message = btoa(message) // Base 64 encoded

console.log(message)

message = atob(message) // Base 63 decoded

console.log(message)

</script>
```

This base 64 encodes the message, prints it, then base 64 decodes this.

**EDIT**
If you want it to display in the page, you can use innerHTML, like this:

```html
<div id="output">

</div>

<script>
  var output = document.getElementById("output") // get the output
  var message = "Hello world!" // Input

  base64 = btoa(message) // base64 encode
  noBase64 = atob(base64) // base64 decode

  output.innerHTML = "Encoded: " + base64 + "<br>Decoded: " + noBase64 // Write to div element
</script>
```

Comment: ok, but I want it to print on the page, not on console, because I have the HTML code in Base64, how  can I do it? if you didn't understands my question please contact me on Discord - brokenPipe#6969 - I'll try to explain as much as I can

Comment: You could use innerHTML property, isn't?

Comment: @brokenPipe I edited it. At the bottom, there is another code snippet that shows how to write the output into the page using `innerHTML`.